# Program runs in IDE but not as .jar file

Tags: java, cmd, jar, jakarta-mail, executable-jar

I am creating a larger program that will have emails sent to the users account whenever an event happens, and right now I am just focusing on making the email sending work.

Right now, I have it functioning perfectly in the `IDE` (IntelliJ) with no errors or warnings, but after I `jar` the file and run it in the `terminal` I get an error every time the program tries to send an email.

I am assuming I jarred the file wrong since it works in the `IDE` perfectly fine, but I am not too sure. I have looked up similar issues to mine but have not found a working solution.

This is the file that has issues in the `terminal`

```
package handler;

import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Sender {

    private Sender(){}

    private static final String SENDERS_GMAIL = "myemail@email.com";
    private static final String SENDERS_PASSWORD = "mypassword";

    private static final String RECEIEVES_EMAIL = "myemail@email.com";

    private static Properties mailServerProperties;
    private static Session mailSession;
    private static MimeMessage mailMessage;

    public static void sendMail(String emailBody) throws Throwable
    {
        mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties);

        mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        mailMessage.addRecipient(RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(RECEIEVES_EMAIL));
        mailMessage.setSubject("Test Email");
        mailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", SENDERS_GMAIL, SENDERS_PASSWORD);
        transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

And whenever I run the `.jar` in the `terminal`, this is the error I get:

```
    C:\Users\genlap\EmailSender>java -jar SendEmail.jar
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for smtp
        at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:460)
        at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:655)
        at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:636)
        at handler.Sender.sendMail(Sender.java:37)
        at handler.ManageService.run(ManageService.java:32)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Message failed to be sent.
```

The line in the `Sender` file that is being called out in the error is

```
Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Comment: See if the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980408/java-mail-no-provider-for-smtp) help.

Comment: @PM77-1 unfortunately no that did not help. I believe I already have all the required dependencies properly added to the `.jar`. But I could always be wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are either not including the dependencies in the `SendEmail.jar` or it lacks  `MANIFEST.MF` entries which point to them. Due to that dependencies which IntelliJ is using for building and running the application are not available when you are executing `java -jar` from the command line.

The easiest way would be to create a fat JAR with all dependencies. If you use Maven you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39275761/1602555) or use [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I created a "fat" JAR as you described, but the issue still persists. I am guessing the issue is with the `MANIFEST.MF` now, but since this is an automatically generated file I am not sure how I could fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What build tools are you using to create the JAR? Maven? Or are you using IntelliJ?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating your application by taking the class files out of the JavaMail jar file and putting them in your application jar file, then you're missing all the META-INF files from the JavaMail jar file.  The best approach is to find a solution that does not require repackaging the JavaMail jar file, such as [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I am using the JavaMail jar files as a whole, I am not taking the individual class files out and adding them to the application. I have a lot of .jar `dependencies` that I am just telling the `IDE` to pack in to the outputted application file I am creating

Comment: How is the IDE adding these jar files to the application file?  What do you see if you look inside the application jar file that is created?